# Render body from function react

Tags: reactjs

I have the following React class

```
class Cards extends React.Component {
  //state 
  //axios-> set new state

  render(){

     const{t} = this.props;

  return(

      // something
      <RenderCards t={t}/>
   )};
  }
```

And my RenderCards:

```
  let RenderCards = (props) => {

    const {t} = props;
    // do something with t
  }
```

The thing is that I also want to pass the state with the props but the following approach is not working :

```
  <RenderCards t={t} st={st}/> //st is this.state

  let RenderCars = (props,st) =>{

  const {st} = st; // -->is undefined!

  }
```

How should I properly pass the state? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the things that you pass as JSX attributes will go into the `props` argument of your stateless component; it doesn't matter where they came from originally. So the signature of `RenderCards` will always be `props => JSX.Element`:

```
let RenderCards = (props) => {
    const { t, st } = props;
    // do something with t and st
};
```

Personally I would remove the definition of `RenderCards` outside of the parent component as well, to avoid unnecessarily redefining it every time the parent is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Here `<RenderCards t={t} st={st}/>` the state is passed as a prop. It won't be available as second function parameter (which is now deprecated `context`):

```
let RenderCards = (props, st) =>{...}
```

It is:

```
let RenderCards = (props) =>{
  const {st} = props;
  ...
}
```